DDS RTI IDL #Include on Java using rtiddsgen
I'm working on a project using RTI Connext DDS (version 6.0.1) for a distributed system and am facing an issue with my IDL setup. My goal is to use a struct defined in one IDL file (Example1.idl) from another struct in a different IDL file (Example2.idl), with both structs residing in separate modules. I attempted to utilize the #include directive and the -I option in my rtiddsgen command to resolve the types across modules, but I keep encountering the following error:
member type 'ExampleModule1::ExampleStruct1' not found.
Project Structure:______
IDLTesting:
├─ idl/
│  ├─ Example1.idl
│  └─ Example2.idl
└─ generate.cmd
Example1.idl:__
module ExampleModule1 {
    struct ExampleStruct1 {
        long id;
        string name;
    };
};


Example2.idl:_______________
#include "Example1.idl"
module ExampleModule2 {
    struct ExampleStruct2 {
        ExampleModule1::ExampleStruct1 refStruct;
        double additionalData;
    };
};


generate.cmd:_______________
rtiddsgen "%NDDSHOME%\bin\rtiddsgen.bat" --ppDisable -language Java -d generated idl/Example2.idl -I idl

Could anyone advise on what might be going wrong here? Is there a specific way to structure the IDL files or a particular command syntax that I should use to successfully reference structs across modules in RTI Connext DDS?
Any insights or examples of how to correctly set up and generate code for this scenario would be greatly appreciated!

You are using the option
--ppDisable
in your rtiddsgen command, and that disables the preprocessor.  At the same time, you are using #include, which is something that is handled by the preprocessor.
You need to run the same command without the --ppDisable, so that the files get preprocessed and the #include is resolved.
